# Problems with Scanner input

Tags: input

I am new to JAVA. I don't understand why JAVA give me two souts.
(Input row & column (throw 1 space): Input row & column (throw 1 space): )

In the first pass, it does not wait for my input and think str = "". And in the second pass its waiting for my input.

Ssory, I forgot to tell that beforе this block of code - my Scanner was opened. I asked program:

```
            while (true) {
            System.out.print("Enter game size (3 - 20): ");
            if (SCAN.hasNextInt()) {
                return SCAN.nextInt();
            }
            System.out.println(SCAN.next() + " - not a number!");
```

I think I should clear scanners buffer ( /n ). But I dont know how.

```
    private static void humanTurn() {
    System.out.println("HUMAN TURN");
    String str;
    String regex = "\\d{1,2}\\s\\d{1,2}";
    Pattern myPattern = Pattern.compile(regex);         // Pattern for checking
    boolean checkPattern;
    int x, y;

    do {
        do {
            System.out.print("Input row & column (throw 1 space): ");
            str = SCAN.nextLine();
            Matcher myMatcher = myPattern.matcher(str);
            checkPattern = myMatcher.matches();
        } while (!checkPattern);

        String[] strArr = str.split(" ");
        x = Integer.parseInt(strArr[0]) - 1;
        y = Integer.parseInt(strArr[1]) - 1;
    } while (!isValidCell(x, y));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to guess your code. This is what I come up with. Still works fine. Let me know if anything else.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    private static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static int size = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        size = getBoardSize();
        humanTurn();
    }

    private static int getBoardSize() {
        while (true) {
            System.out.print("Enter game size (3 - 20): ");
            if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
                return sc.nextInt();
            }
            System.out.println(sc.next() + " - not a number!");
        }
    }

    private static void humanTurn() {
        System.out.println("HUMAN TURN");
        String str;
        String regex = "\\d{1,2}\\s\\d{1,2}";
        Pattern myPattern = Pattern.compile(regex);         // Pattern for checking
        boolean checkPattern;
        int x, y;

        do {
            do {
                System.out.print("Input row & column (throw 1 space): ");
                str = sc.nextLine();
                Matcher myMatcher = myPattern.matcher(str);
                checkPattern = myMatcher.matches();
            } while (!checkPattern);

            String[] strArr = str.split(" ");
            x = Integer.parseInt(strArr[0]) - 1;
            y = Integer.parseInt(strArr[1]) - 1;
        } while (!isValidCell(x, y));
    }

    private static boolean isValidCell(int x, int y) {
        return x < size && y < size && x >= 0 && y >= 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, see my post again. I've added some new information.

Comment: Hey, @vkandrei83 does this work?

Comment: No. Its steel working bad - After u enter a game size, u see double str: Input row & column (throw 1 space): Input row & column (throw 1 space):